# How to fix "Google Mobile Ads SDK was initialized incorrectly" for my Android Soundboard App

Tags: java, android, android-manifest, ads

Adding Google Ad Banners to my Android-Studio Project does not work.
I would be very very thankful, if anyone could help me. I just do not understand what I did wrong. :/
The tutorial I followed was: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w7muIkMYE_A

EDIT: Now I changed the code a bit and a new error occured.
Android Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="de.codereddev.howtoandroidsoundboard">

       ...

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

<!--
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/filepaths"/>
-->
        <meta-data
            android:name ="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713"/>

        <activity
            android:name=".SoundboardActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".FavoriteActivity" />

        <!-- Necessary for sharing sounds on Android 5.1+  -->
        <provider
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileprovider"
            android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        </provider>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

No changes in my SoundboardActivity class:

```
    public class SoundboardActivity
        extends AppCompatActivity implements 
        LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<ArrayList<SoundObject>> {

        AdView mAdview;

...

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_soundboard);

    MobileAds.initialize(this, "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713");
    mAdview = (AdView)findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR).build();
    mAdview.loadAd(adRequest);
     ...
```

The new error is:

```
03-24 21:28:53.943 24135-24135/de.codereddev.howtoandroidsoundboard    
    E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        Process: de.codereddev.howtoandroidsoundboard, PID: 24135
        java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider android.support.v4.content.FileProvider: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Missing android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS meta-data
            at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:6396)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:5938)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5853)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:199)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1650)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
         Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Missing android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS meta-data
            at android.support.v4.content.FileProvider.parsePathStrategy(FileProvider.java:608)
            at android.support.v4.content.FileProvider.getPathStrategy(FileProvider.java:579)
            at android.support.v4.content.FileProvider.attachInfo(FileProvider.java:392)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:6391)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:5938) 
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5853) 
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:199) 
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1650) 
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669) 
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
            at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

Answer (score 15):

Maybe the problem in the   Manifest file..

Try Manifest the below type ..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
    <!-- Sample AdMob App ID: ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713 -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
        android:value="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713"/>

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for helping me! I edited the question above to show you the new circumstances!

Comment: If u can not fix it, you can check my project on GitHub https://github.com/Kangkankarmaker/admob2

Comment: Thanks a lot! I've been struggling with this issue for 1 day or so, because I put the `<meta-data>` part inside the `<activity>` instead of directly within `<application>` node. Works like a charm now.

Answer (score 5):

**Update your AndroidManifest.xml**

Add your AdMob App ID to your app's AndroidManifest.xml file by adding a  tag with name com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID, as shown below.

You can find your App ID in the AdMob UI. For android:value insert your own AdMob App ID in quotes, as shown below.

```
<manifest>
    <application>
        <!-- Sample AdMob App ID: ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713 -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx~yyyyyyyyyy"/>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

See more info in [admob](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/quick-start#update_your_androidmanifestxml)  or [GeetMark](https://geetmark.com/)